# Subversion: Working copy is old development version

Tags: macos, svn, cornerstone

I'm developing on OSX, and one of my Subversion working copies just started returning the following error for all commands, however my other checkouts work fine. I get the same message with both my Brew installed SVN binaries as well as my Cornerstone client, but other working directories are fine.

```
> svn update
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/working_directory' is an old development version (format 12); to upgrade it, use a format 18 client, then use 'tools/dev/wc-ng/bump-to-19.py', then use the current client
> svn upgrade
svn: E155019: Can't upgrade '/working_directory' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory
svn: E150000: Missing default entry
```

I don't have the `bump-to-19.py` script anywhere on my computer (according to `find / -type f -name bump-to-19.py`), however I think I was able to find it on the [Apache repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/dev/wc-ng/bump-to-19.py). That said, I am not familiar with what it does, or how to use it. Ideally I can avoid checking out a new version of this working directory and manually merging in all of my (many) changes.

The only info I was able to find is related to [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Subversion1_7) and `javahl`, and I'm using neither.

**EDIT**: After downloading the `bump-to-19.py` file and making it executable, I tried it against my working directory to no avail:

```
> ./bump-to-19.py working_directory/
error: format is 29 not 18: 'working_directory/'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although I was not able to figure out why my working directory was corrupted, I was able to work around it using `rsync` - there is an option, `C`, that will ignore CVS/SVN files and directories when making a backup. I made a backup using this option, checked out the project again, and then copied the backup back over the new working directory. SVN is happy again.

```
> rsync -arC working_directory working_directory_no_svn
> rm -rf working_directory
> svn co https://svn.example.com/project/trunk working_directory
> rsync -ar working_directory_no_svn working_directory
```

Comment: Neat solution, but I think the one posted by user1794106 is easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and here is how I resolved:

1. Delete the .svn folder at the top level (rm -rf .svn)
2. Checkout software again from SVN (svn co ...)
3. Good to go!

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been around a while, but I found a solution using the hints given by SVN... Basically use the upgrade command as it states.  Using CMD, I went to my workspace folder where the troubled project was located. Lets call the project Project1. You call the command:

"svn upgrade project1"

this resolved my issue the proper way without involving some sort of hack or workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm. I should note that `cd project1; svn upgrade`, which I initially tried, does not work.

Comment: Just wanted to add a note on your answer that I *did* try to run `svn upgrade project_name` but got the same error message as the other svn commands. Definitely worth trying this option first though, much cleaner if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my svn is version 1.7.10, however my Subversion plugin for Eclipse is slightly older, I'm assuming 1.6.something.

Using the "rsync -arC working_directory archive_no_svn" command was a breakthrough - at least now I had a copy of the hours of synchronisation I had just completed.

I tried using the "svn co" but it was the wrong version, so I simply ran an update using the Subversion plugin within Eclipse - this restored the working directory from the repository - pretty much what I was after, and it was the correct version.

Getting the rsync back to the correct location was a trick.  rsync appears to drop the working folder into the archive location, creating archive_location/working_directory/the-files.  So syncing the archived data back into the working_directory was achieved with:
rsync -ar archive_no_svn/working_directory .

Now I have to find out about upgrading my Subversion plugin for Eclipse to 1.7